# What`s result of converting char* to int*

Tags: c++

The code is below：

```
int main(void) {
    char* str = "12345678";
    int* in = (int*)str;
    printf("%d\n%d\n", in[0], in[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

What is result? Why?

Comment: What do you think the result is, and why? And what is the "practical problem that you are trying to solve"? And did you know that your `str` initialisation is illegal since 2011? I'm calling the police lol. In all seriousness, this sounds like a parroted homework question without any research effort so I'm interested to hear more from you before I consider answering. Good luck!

Comment: Change format in `printf()` from `%d` to `%x` , this may enlight you on what's happening.

Comment: @IT_CZL: Please check if you are satisfied with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> What is result?

Implementation defined.

> Why?

Because the standard says so.

§5.2.10.7

> An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type. When a prvalue v of
>   object pointer type is converted to the object pointer type “pointer to cv T”, the result is static_cast(static_cast(v)). Converting a prvalue of type “pointer to T1” to the type “pointer to
>   T2” (where T1 and T2 are object types and where the alignment requirements of T2 are no stricter than
>   those of T1) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value.

BTW, this is illegal in c++: `char* str = "12345678";` as string literals are const. To be correct it should be: `const char* str = "12345678";`

Comment: Why do you think it is implementation defined?  I am pretty sure that accessing a char array through a pointer to int is UB (not just implementation defined).  For one thing, the array may not be suitably aligned.

Comment: @MartinBonner it's an explicit reinterpret_cast from a char pointer. That is legal. The result is left to the implementation, but it's not UB.

Comment: @RichardHodges it's only legal if the original data that the `char *` points to was int

Comment: as you just quoted yourself `back to its original type yields the original pointer value` is the key phrase here. If it never was int data it's undefined

Comment: @PeterT it's only *defined* if the original data was int. How else are we able to retrieve encoded byte streams off a network?

Comment: @RichardHodges right. but the original data in the OP was not `int`. So it's not defined. And your quote doesn't cover the access the OP does (via `int*` to a data declared `char *`.

Comment: How else are we able to retrieve encoded byte streams off a network?  By reading each octet, and combining them into a int (or other type) as required.  Doing a `reinterpret_cast` and then indirecting through the pointer is undefined behaviour - which doesn't mean it doesn't work on your platform.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is (for my system)

```
875770417
943142453
```

Here goes the reason :
str points to "12345678". In my system int is 4 bytes. So *in points to "1234" and *in+1 points to "5678".
Inside the memory char is stored in binary form.

Now lets have look at in[0]. in[0] would evaluate "1234". The memory representation would be this (in binary):

```
00110001 00110010 00110011 00110100
```

(These are ascii values for 1, 2, 3, 4 which are - 49, 50, 51, 52)

Now as you have assigned char to int, now the compiler will load the about 32 bits as one word. Depending upon **BIG ENDIAN or LITTLE ENDIAN** evaluation will happen. My system is LITTLE ENDIAN.
So my evaluation happened this way -

```
 52*(2^24) + 51*(2^16) + 50*(2^8) + 49 = 8775770417
```

Similar interpretation for in[1]. Hope this clears things.

Comment: Your system is little endian due to the hardware, not which OS you use.

Comment: Actually Ubuntu 16.04 runs on both big-endian (powerpc) and little-endian (everything else) architectures.

Comment: @Colin__s: Except that *some* hardware is switchable, and then the OS gets to choose.

Answer (score 0):

The result is *undefined behaviour*, which [n4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) (the final draft of C++ 14) defines as

> behavior for which this International Standard imposes no requirements

*Anything* can happen.  Seg fault, hard drive wiped, etc.  A quite plausible result is that the ASCII characters "1234" are treated as the bytes of a four byte little endian integer, and the resulting number printed out (and similarly for "5678") - but don't rely on this.